# What's the difference between require.main and module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a cli with node, and when I had to reference the filepath of the module, I didn't understand how it worked.

From node's docs, it says that `require.main === module`. What specifically do these mean ?

Answer (score 15):

From the doc ;

> When a file is run directly from Node.js, require.main is set to its
>   module. That means that you can determine whether a file has been run
>   directly by testing

```
require.main === module
```

> For a file foo.js, this will be true if run via node foo.js, but false
>   if run by require('./foo').

So lets say you have a file called foo.js and it involves the following code;

```
console.log(require.main === module);
```

When you type " node foo.js " from terminal , you will see that it returns true. But let s say you have a second file called foo1.js and you require foo.js in this file as the following ;

```
var foo = require("./foo");
```

When you type " node foo1.js " from terminal , you will see that it returns false.

This is what this part of docs is telling.